# What's the simplest way to display progress when downloading image data? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a small app that loads random images from a Flickr search. Everything works fine, but since I'm constructing my UIImage using the data constructor, it takes a while for the user to be able to see any changes after imputing their query.

**What's the simplest way through which I can evaluate and display the progress of the image data being downloaded?**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: still sort of banging my head against this. :/

Answer (score 0):

[UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage) is written for famous [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which adds functionality of showing activity indicator to it. That may solve your problem